# Como montar o foreach para pegar valores do array

Tags: php, foreach

Boa tarde.
Como devo montar o `foreach` para pegar os valores:

- barcode;
- link;
- charge.

deste `array`:

```
array (
  'code' => 200,
  'data' => 
  array (
    'barcode' => '00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000',
    'link' => 'https://visualizacaosandbox.gerencianet.com.br/emissao/196843_16_MEHZE5/A4XB-AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA',
    'pdf' => 
    array (
      'charge' => 'https://download.gerencianet.com.br/196843_16_MEHZE5/196843-AAAAAA-AAAAAA.pdf?sandbox=true',
    ),
    'expire_at' => '2019-09-04',
    'charge_id' => 758277,
    'status' => 'waiting',
    'total' => 10000,
    'payment' => 'banking_billet',
  ),
)
```

PHP

```
foreach ($row_rs["dataBoleto"]["data"] as $row) {
  echo $row["code"];
}
```

Obrigado.

### var_dump($row_rs);

```
array(20) { ["ID_Receita"]=> string(2) "20" ["id_cadastro"]=> string(2) "11" ["nome"]=> string(20) "Aluno de teste teste" ["matricula"]=> string(14) "70-47064508-19" ["parcela"]=> string(6) "1 de 4" ["planoDeConta"]=> string(5) "1.1.3" ["valor"]=> string(6) "175.00" ["dataLanc"]=> string(10) "2019-09-03" ["dataVenci"]=> string(10) "2019-10-03" ["dataPago"]=> NULL ["contaBancaria"]=> string(1) "2" ["formaEntrada"]=> string(1) "6" ["obs"]=> NULL ["cheqNomeProprietario"]=> NULL ["cheqBanco"]=> NULL ["cheqAgencia"]=> NULL ["cheqConta"]=> NULL ["cheqNumero"]=> NULL ["cheqDataDeposito"]=> NULL ["dataBoleto"]=> string(409) "{"code":200,"data":{"barcode":"00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000","link":"https://visualizacaosandbox.gerencianet.com.br/emissao/196843_16_MEHZE5/A4XB-AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA","pdf":{"charge":"https://download.gerencianet.com.br/196843_16_MEHZE5/AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA.pdf?sandbox=true"},"expire_at":"2019-09-04","charge_id":758277,"status":"waiting","total":10000,"payment":"banking_billet"}}" }
```

Comment: Tentou assim: `echo $row["barcode"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa do `foreach` para isso.

```php
$data    = $row_rs["dataBoleto"]["data"];
$barcode = $data["barcode"];
$link    = $data["link"];
$charge  = $data["pdf"]["charge"];
```

Se precisar percorrer por vários itens dentro de `$row_rs`, você precisará:

```php
foreach($row_rs as $dataBoleto) {
    $data    = $dataBoleto["data"];
    $barcode = $data["barcode"];
    $link    = $data["link"];
    $charge  = $data["pdf"]["charge"];
}
```

Você só precisa percorrer pelos sub-arrays dentro do seu `row`.

---

### Atualização

No seu *var_dump*, o índice `"dataBoleto"` contém uma string JSON dentro:

```
["dataBoleto"]=> string(409)
```

Portanto, você deverá converter antes para um objeto notável antes de trabalhar com ele. No exemplo, ficaria mais ou menos isso:

```php
$dataParsed = json_decode($row_rs["dataBoleto"], true /* para Array */);

$data    = $dataParsed["data"];
$barcode = $data["barcode"];
$link    = $data["link"];
$charge  = $data["pdf"]["charge"];
```

E então, dentro de `$dataParsed`, terá os objetos como um `array` e não uma `string`.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda. Esta aparecendo esse erro `Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in`

Comment: @Tiago o array que colocou no status pertence a que objeto?

Comment: Todo o array esta dentro do `$row_rs["dataBoleto"]`

Comment: Estranho, porque no exemplo, `$row_rs["dataBoleto"]` contém o índice `data`, que aponta para o restante do conteúdo. Coloca na sua publicação o `var_dump` de `row_rs`.

Comment: Atualizei o código

Comment: @Tiago atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98299/discussion-between-tiago-and-cypherpotato).